# Get p values for a specific variable in many models with all possible combinations of other independent variables

Tags: r, model, lm

I am trying to run many regression models with all possible combinations of a set of independent variables.

In this example, I am interested in the coefficients of `cyl` with all possible combinations of other variables listed in `xlist`.

```
df <- mtcars
md <- "mpg ~ cyl" 
xlist <- c("disp", "hp", "am")
n <- length(xlist)
# get a list of all possible combinations of xlist 
comb_lst <- unlist(lapply(1:n, function(x) combn(xlist, x, simplify=F)), recursive = F)
# get a list of all models
md_lst <- lapply(comb_lst, function(x) paste(md, "+", paste(x, collapse = "+")))
# run those models and obtain coefficients for cyl
coefs <- unlist(lapply(md_lst, function(x) lm(as.formula(x),data=df)$coe[2]))
```

It works fine to get all coefficients for `cyl`. However, I don't know how to get the p value corresponding to each of those coefficients.

```
pvalues <- lapply(md, function(x) lm(as.formula(x),data=df)$?[2]))
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below, feel  free to let me know if it is not what you need.

Comment: After running your second code: Error: 'extract_model_info' is not an exported object from 'namespace:manymodelr'
Called from: getExportedValue(pkg, name)

Comment: Yes, it is not available in 0.2.2 because I only added it recently and do not intend to push to cran until after several months. So, please try the developer version as in my comment below. I'll see if I can write an answer that does not rely on using an external package.

Comment: Added an answer that negates the need for  packages.

Comment: The p-values hide in the `summary()`., try `pvalues <- lapply(md_lst, function(x) summary(lm(as.formula(x),data=df))$coe["cyl", 4])`.

Comment: @jay.sf This is an excellent approach. It is easy to understand and I am going to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer::** This answer uses the developer version of [manymodelr](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr/tree/develop) that I also happen to have written. You can then go on to choose only those variables you are interested in.

```
Map(function(x) manymodelr::extract_model_info(x,"p_value"),
  lapply(md_lst, function(x) do.call(lm, list(formula = x, data=mtcars))))

# Just cyl
Map(function(x) manymodelr::extract_model_info(x,"p_value")["cyl"],
  lapply(md_lst, function(x) do.call(lm, list(formula = x, data=mtcars))))
```

**If you don't want to use packages:**

```
Map(function(x) coef(summary(x))[,4]["cyl"],
  lapply(md_lst, function(x) do.call(lm, list(formula = x, data=mtcars))))
```

**Results::(first part)**

```
[[1]]
 (Intercept)          cyl         disp 
4.022869e-14 3.366495e-02 5.418572e-02 

[[2]]
 (Intercept)          cyl           hp 
1.620660e-16 4.803752e-04 2.125285e-01 

[[3]]
 (Intercept)          cyl           am 
7.694408e-14 1.284560e-07 5.635445e-02 

[[4]]
 (Intercept)          cyl         disp           hp 
1.537198e-13 1.349044e-01 8.092901e-02 3.249519e-01 

[[5]]
 (Intercept)          cyl         disp           am 
2.026114e-12 2.823412e-02 1.544849e-01 1.610559e-01 

[[6]]
 (Intercept)          cyl           hp           am 
9.270924e-12 8.635578e-02 1.692706e-02 5.464020e-03 

[[7]]
 (Intercept)          cyl         disp           hp           am 
3.724625e-11 2.800850e-01 4.760672e-01 4.416647e-02 2.520516e-02
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @NelsonGon. You are so quick. I just installed `manymodelr` 0.2.2. It is not working on my machine. I guess that I have to get the developer version. Don't know how yet.

Comment: You need the developer version(0.2.3). You can install it by using `devtools`. So `install.packages("devtools")`;`devtools::install_github("Nelson-Gon/manymodelr@develop")`. However, what errors did you get on installation?

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach for each coefficient of `cyl` with **no** package:

```
pvalues <- lapply(md_lst, function(x) summary(lm(as.formula(x),data=df))$coefficients[,4])

[[1]]
 (Intercept)          cyl         disp 
4.022869e-14 3.366495e-02 5.418572e-02 

[[2]]
 (Intercept)          cyl           hp 
1.620660e-16 4.803752e-04 2.125285e-01 

[[3]]
 (Intercept)          cyl           am 
7.694408e-14 1.284560e-07 5.635445e-02 

[[4]]
 (Intercept)          cyl         disp           hp 
1.537198e-13 1.349044e-01 8.092901e-02 3.249519e-01 

[[5]]
 (Intercept)          cyl         disp           am 
2.026114e-12 2.823412e-02 1.544849e-01 1.610559e-01 

[[6]]
 (Intercept)          cyl           hp           am 
9.270924e-12 8.635578e-02 1.692706e-02 5.464020e-03 

[[7]]
 (Intercept)          cyl         disp           hp           am 
3.724625e-11 2.800850e-01 4.760672e-01 4.416647e-02 2.520516e-02
```

Using `broom::glance` for all:

```
pvalues <- lapply(md_lst, function(x) glance(summary(lm(as.formula(x),data=df)))$p.value)

[[1]]
[1] 1.057904e-09

[[2]]
[1] 3.161781e-09

[[3]]
[1] 1.093687e-09

[[4]]
[1] 5.053802e-09

[[5]]
[1] 3.060153e-09

[[6]]
[1] 4.790959e-10

[[7]]
[1] 2.540038e-09
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. P values appear to be for the whole model, rather than the coefficient of  `cyl`

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang I've edited my response and yet kept the old one too as it might be useful for others.